# How to prevent script tags in text from executing?

Tags: javascript, html

I had a text box in my browser. Whatever you typed in the text box and clicked on <kbd>okay</kbd> button, the text submitted server through a AJAX request and  then spread that message to remaining people, including to  me also.

The message is appeared on a `<div>`.

What's my problem is if I typed html or script tags in that message they are not appearing in the message `<div>` and they are executing .

If I typed like tags opened and end with script in that middle code is executing on client side, how can I prevent executing and I am able to spread `<script>` tags also in the messages spreading to all.

Comment: Handle your text as text, not HTML.

Comment: @alex Indeed. Consider an answer ;-)

Comment: @psd Thanks, and OK, I shall write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text to always be text, treat is as text and don't use it to set `innerHTML` property for example.

Update text nodes instead.

#### Update

For example, if you had user input in `userInput`, and you wanted to display it, you would treat it as text, not HTML.

```
var element = document.body,
    // For example
    userInput = "Alex <script>alert('xss')</script>";

// Don't do this! Your input is text, not HTML.
// element.innerHTML = userInput;

// Use this instead
if ('textContent' in element) {
    element.textContent = userInput;
} else {
    element.innerText = userInput;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/YwNk7/).

Comment: thanks @alex .but i did'nt understood .you only understood my problem ..please give me in breif ..please .please

Comment: use it to set innerHTML property for example. what is means ??
and  how to update text nodes instead .

Comment: @suresh See update. You will need to do a little research by yourself as well.

Comment: and one more doubt ...if(`textContent` in element) ..what does that special symbols above  text content shown??

Comment: @suresh See updated code, I accidentally used backticks as string delimiters :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing with html character entities? For example replacing all `<` with `&lt;`.