# Preventing XSS in innerHTML attribute

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss, innerhtml

I have this following code

```
   nver+="<SPAN CLASS=focusField>"+text.substring(start,end)+"</SPAN>";
   if(text.length>end)
   nver+=text.substring(end,text.length);
   results.innerHTML=nver.replace(/[\n]/g,"<BR>");
```

so the text variable is tampered with

```
textarea:ABCD"> < img/src='x'onerror=alert('XSS')>
```

First `text.substring(start,end)` has output `'textarea'` 
and `text.substring(end,text.length)` has the remaining `:ABCD">< img/src='x'onerror=alert('XSS')>`

How to counter this XSS? Is there some way I can use createtextnode or some functionality to counter this? If so how do I do it using `createtextnode`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent script tags in text from executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5440607/90527)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to HTML encode your output

```
  function htmlEscape(str) {
        return String(str)
                .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
                .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
  }

  nver+=text.substring(end,text.length);

  // HTML encode (i.e. escape the nver variable for correct output)
  nver = htmlEscape(nver);

  results.innerHTML=nver.replace(/[\n]/g,"<BR>");
```

Check out the [DOM based XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more tips.