# escaping user given text with javascript. Some things 'unescape' when inserted in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to escape user input to place in a page seen by another user, in a manner that avoids XSS.

My text goes inside a div. So, I want to follow the following recommendation:https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content

(that is, I want to escape  & < > " ' and / )

I am using this bit of javascript to do just that

```
escapeHTML: function (unsafe_str) {
                return unsafe_str
                        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                        .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;')
                        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                        .replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
                        .replace(/\'/g, '&#39;');
}
```

The function seems to do what it should, when I print the string to the console.

But, the moment I do `div.innerHTML = escaped_string`, the html has some of the characters "unescaped" (the / " and ' become single characters again, rather than the string)

I tried using other methods to put the string in the page, including jquery. Always got the same result.

What is going on ?

---

To clarify:

The result I want is, that when I have the string `&</>\"'` to add to the document, the html reads `&amp;&lt;&#x2F;&gt;&quot;&#39;` and displays `&</>"'`

What I usually get is a html that reads `&amp;&lt;/&gt;"'` and displays correctly (i.e. `&</>"'`)

(and I am worried about the chars `/"'` being used in some kind of XSS)

Comment: Javascript is javascript, DOM is DOM. If you do good work in javascript, then write the sanitised strings to the DOM, then try to use those strings for anything other than presentation to the user, then (in this scenario) your good work is undone.

Comment: Solutions (a) work with the original strings in javascript, without ever reading back from the DOM, or (b) re-sanitize.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 : I do not want to re-read from the DOM. I was just checking if the escaping worked. Having those chars back there seems to mean that I did not follow the recommentation, and am vulnerable to XSS...

Comment: Ah OK, verification. I didn't understand that from the question (as you already know :) ). In that case, stick the string into an input field with `.val(str)` or into a span/div/p with `.text(str)`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anx6m2x7/)**

Comment: I can post that as an answer or you can just accept Barman's answer, which is correct, though I'm not sure it's correct for the right reason.

Comment: Thanks, but it has the same problem. I might not have explained it all that well.I added some clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent script tags in text from executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5440607/90527)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead of `.innerHTML`. Then the data will be inserted literally, instead of being parsed as HTML, so you don't need to convert special characters to entities.

HTML:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("target").textContent = "<a>This is not a link & you can't click on it</a>";
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8rrsnj24/1/)

IE8 and earlier doesn't support `.textContent`, use `.innerText`. Here's a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/joshrhoades/8874249)

Comment: That's only good if it's ok to present "&amp;" etc to the user. What if the OP intends to present "&" etc?

Comment: Where is `&amp;` coming from? My intent is that he do this _instead_ of replacing all the special characters with entities.

Comment: OK, then we have understood the question differently. I can't say your're wrong but the string replacements seem to be central to the objective - anti-XSS.

Comment: If you assign `.textContent`, there's no XSS possible because the content is not interpreted. Tags are not rendered, scripts are not executed.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good alternative to my original plan. But I'll wait a bit more to see if I can get the original plan to work