# .innerHTML & XSS Prevention

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have the following line of code:

`document.getElementById("div-1").innerHTML = userInput;`

where `userInput` is a user provided variable. I realize that a user could easily insert harmful scripts by inserting something like:

`<img src="/" onerror="alert('attack');"/>`

However, I am unsure if this would be an example of XSS because I feel like that only user that would be affected would be the attacker.

Is this an example of XSS? If so, can you give an example of how an attacker could leverage this vulnerability in the form of an XSS and how this security risk can be mitigated?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158106/facebooks-warning-of-self-xss

Comment: Well if there is a way for one user to share it with another than there is an attack vector.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent script tags in text from executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5440607/90527)

Comment: This helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is XSS. If only the attacker him/herself is affected it is called self XSS. However self XSS can often be chained with other bugs such as CSRF to turn the self XSS into a viable attack vector.

If you assign the userInput to .textContent instead of .innerHTML you instruct the browser to treat the data as text and not HTML.