# How to avoid script execution in innerHTML to prevent xss

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Is there a way to prevent xss while using innerHTML?

One example:

`elem.innerHTML = "Hello <span style='color:red'>There!</span><img src=x onerror=confirm('xss') />");`

there can be many more scenarios like this where we just want to show the Pure view part only in the above case only

`Hello <span style='color:red'>There!</span><img src=x />`

Comment: I think the following answer may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30707806/7432982

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent script tags in text from executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5440607/90527)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `textContent`.

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

> Element.innerHTML returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes people use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element, but textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML.
>
> Moreover, **using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.**

```js
elem.textContent = "Hello <span style='color:red'>There!</span><img src=x onerror=confirm('xss') />";
```

```html
<pre id="elem"></pre>
```